# Salesforce error in email template - Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, email-templates

Around line 30, in the headervalue='Credit' line, it produces the syntax error shown in the Title. Does anyone know why?
I tried getting an answer on the Salesforce forums but was told that everything looks correct and I can use IF conditions within VALUE attributes.
I'm sure this is a simple issue but it's driving us crazy.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Statement" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="c2g__codaMassEmailAccount__c">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <p align="center">
        <img src="{!relatedTo.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__LogoURL__c}"/><br/>
        <small><apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__Street__c}"/><br/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__City__c}"/><apex:outputText value=", "/><apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__StateProvince__c}"/><br/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__ZipPostCode__c}"/><br/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__Country__c}"/><br/>
        <apex:outputText value="Phone: "/><apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__Phone__c}"/><apex:outputText value=" Fax: "/><apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__Fax__c}"/><br/><br/></small>
    </p>
    <p>
        <c2g:CODAFormatterController date="{!TODAY()}"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.c2g__Account__r.Name}"/>
        <br/><br/>
        Hello,
        <br/><br/>
        Please find attached a statement of your account with us. We would appreciate prompt payment of these items.
    </p>
    <br/><br/>
    <apex:dataTable value="{!relatedTo.c2g__MassEmailAccountLineItems__r}" var="line" border="1" cellpadding="3">
        <apex:column style="text-align:left"   headervalue="Document Type"      value="{!line.c2g__Transaction__r.c2g__TransactionType__c}"/>
        <apex:column style="text-align:left"   headervalue="Document Number"    value="{!line.c2g__Transaction__r.c2g__DocumentNumber__c}"/>
        <apex:column style="text-align:left"   headervalue="Document Reference" value="{!line.c2g__Transaction__r.c2g__DocumentReference__c}"/>
        <apex:column style="text-align:center" headervalue="Due Date"           value="{!line.c2g__DueDate__c}"/>

        <apex:column style="text-align:left"   headervalue="Currency"           value="{!line.c2g__TransactionLineItem__r.c2g__DocumentCurrency__r.Name}"/>

        <!-- The line below causes syntax error  -->
        <apex:column style="text-align:left"   headervalue="Credit"             value="{!IF(line.c2g__DocumentOutstandingValue__c<0, ABS(line.c2g__DocumentOutstandingValue__c), 0)}" />
        <apex:column style="text-align:left"   headervalue="Debit"              value="{!line.c2g__DocumentOutstandingValue__c}"/>


    </apex:dataTable>

    <br/>
    <!--
        <apex:column style="text-align:right"  headervalue="Outstanding Amount"><c2g:CODAFormatterController number="{!IF(line.c2g__Transaction__r.c2g__TransactionType__c!='Journal',ABS(line.c2g__DocumentOutstandingValue__c),line.c2g__DocumentOutstandingValue__c)}" currency="{!line.c2g__TransactionLineItem__r.c2g__DocumentCurrency__r.Name}"/>
    -->
    <p>
        If you have any questions about this payment please do not hesitate to contact us at accountsreceivable.     
        <br/><br/>
        Thank you,
        <br/><br/>
        {!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}
    </p>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
```

Comment: Just wild guessing here, but try wrapping `line.c2g__DocumentOutstandingValue__c<0` in round brackets